# How can I change the order of correct answers or accept more than just one global answer?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am still working on my question bot and now I want you to be able to give multiple `correct_answers`. Here is what I had in mind: Each user can execute a command 3x to give an answer. But to each question I want a different solution to be considered correct, so not always just `A`, as an example. How can I make the bot consider the following answers as correct in the order: `A, B, A` or `A, B, C` etc.

At the moment I have the following code:

```py
correct_answers = "A" #Only possibility

    @commands.command()
    async def answer(self, ctx, answer):
        self.answer.enabled = False
        global correct_answers
        if correct_answers != answer:
            await ctx.author.send(f "You guessed {answer} which is **wrong**. Good luck next time!")
            await ctx.message.delete()
            return
            [shortened]
            await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.author.send(f'The right answer was **{correct_answers}**, you guessed **correctly**!')
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        self.answer.enabled = True
```

***My embed code where I want to decide after which edit which answer is correct:***

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def trivia_c(self, ctx):

        e = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        e.title = "New question, new luck."
        e.description = "**When was Steve Jobs born?**"
        e.add_field(name="1️⃣", value="02/24/1955", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="2️⃣", value="03/24/1955", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="3️⃣", value="02/24/1965", inline=False)
        e.set_footer(text="You have x-x to answer this question.", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        e.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        question = await ctx.send(embed=e)

        await asyncio.sleep(10)

        e2 = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        e2.title = "New question, new luck."
        e2.description = "Test1"
        e2.add_field(name="1️⃣", value="02/24/1955")
        e2.add_field(name="2️⃣", value="03/24/1955")
        e2.add_field(name="3️⃣", value="02/24/1965")
        e2.set_footer(text="You have x-x to answer this question.")
        e2.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await question.edit(embed=e2)

        await asyncio.sleep(10)

        e3 = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        e3.title = "Test2"
        e3.description = "When was Steve Jobs born?"
        e3.add_field(name="1️⃣", value="02/24/1955")
        e3.add_field(name="2️⃣", value="03/24/1955")
        e3.add_field(name="3️⃣", value="02/24/1965")
        e3.set_footer(text="You have x-x to answer this question.")
        e3.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await question.edit(embed=e3)

        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

My **approach** would have been to do it via an **enumeration**, i.e.
`first, second, third = "A", "B", "A"` or `correct_answers = ["A", "B", "B"]` but in both cases it doesn't work. Would I have to go through a **list** and how exactly do I do that? I also read that you can get the results via an **index**, but then it fails for me.

***In summary:***
The first execution of the command should recognize `A` as correct, then the second time for example `B`, and the third time for example `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the embed code provided I have used wait_for like my previous example. Still reduces the need for a second command. If you wanted you would have to implement a storage system. I have done the first command as an example. If you wanted to set a limit you can use `timeout=seconds` in the `wait_or`

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def trivia_c(self, ctx):
        def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel
        e = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        e.title = "New question, new luck."
        e.description = "**When was Steve Jobs born?**"
        e.add_field(name="1️⃣", value="02/24/1955", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="2️⃣", value="03/24/1955", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="3️⃣", value="02/24/1965", inline=False)
        e.set_footer(text="You have x-x to answer this question.", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        e.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        question = await ctx.send(embed=e)
        try:
            reply = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
            if reply.content == "a":
                print("Good")
            else:
                print("bad")
            await reply.delete()
        except:
            return await question.edit(content="You took too long, so the question is gone.")
        

        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        # Next
```

Comment: The reason I made the second command is because I wanted to built in a cooldown for their answers. If they now just spam "A" I guess every answer will be counted, am I wrong? I made a storage system which grants points on the correct answer. If they type `answer A`, which is defined as the right answer, they will get 10 points. I can easily implement that into your shortened version but how do I now accomplish that a user can't submit another answer before the embed is edited?

Comment: on_wait only allows 1 reply so spamming "A" wouldn't work because by the time the next wait_for is executed that will execute. Then you have @command.cooldown on the trivia_c command which means they can do that command every so often.

Comment: Your code seems to work nearly fine. I want the author of the reply messaged in a DM about a right or wrong answer. I also think you mixed your first answer with the second one? Can't find `question_sent` in the second answer. The printing also does not seem to work for some reason and I do not really want the embed to be edited with an `except` event or something else, are alternatives possible?

Comment: You can do `ctx.author.send("wrong")` to dm the author. And the except statement is the only way to edit it. Fixed the answer

Comment: Thanks. All in all not what I was really looking for but I will then built it for myself with the given answers.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

@commands.command()
async def question(self, ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel
    
    question_one = "How many lives do cat's have?"
    answers_one = {"9":"a","1":"b","10":"c"}

    questions = {question_one:{"9":answers_one}, "Pineapple on pizza?":{"yes":{"yes":"a", 
        "no":"b"}}}

    # get a question
    question = random.choice(list(questions.keys()))
    data = questions.get(question)
    correct_answer = list(data.keys())[0]
    answers = list(list(data.values())[0].items())
    question_msg = ""
    answers_msg = ""

    numbers_list = []
    answers_list = []

    for answer, number in answers:
        numbers_list.append(number)
        answers_list.append(answer)

    while numbers_list != []:
        num = random.choice(numbers_list)
        ans = random.choice(answers_list)
        answers_msg += f"{num}. {ans}\n"
        answers_list.remove(ans)
        numbers_list.remove(num)

    question_msg = f"{question}\nPlease pick one of the following:\n{answers_msg}"
    question_sent = await ctx.send(question_msg)
    try:
        reply = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    except:
        return await question_sent.edit(content="You took too long, so the question is gone.")
    await reply.delete()
    if reply.content == correct_answer:
        await ctx.send("Well done!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Nope. How can you get confused!")
```

This uses [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) which means you can share the data and not need multiple commands.
This supports the use of multiple questions.

During testing I got:

```
How many lives do cat's have?
Please pick one of the following:
c. 1
b. 10
a. 9
```

```
How many lives do cat's have?
Please pick one of the following:
a. 10
b. 9
c. 1
```

Comment: I understand your code, but maybe we misunderstood each other a bit. I would like to determine for myself which solution is considered correct. I have an event that posts an embed, asking a question and gives answer options. This edits itself 3x and each time I would like to be able to say: For embed 1 A is correct, for 2 only C and for 3 B, or something like that. Based on that the command `answer` should output "wrong" after the first execution, if "B" or "C" as picked, other way around for the other solutions. Do you want me to add the embed code to my question?

Comment: @Dominik you are over complicating it

Comment: The problem is: I already have an existing code which gives out the questions I want. The `asyncio` event I built in edits the question and gives the possibility to answer. I do not really want random questions or a changed order for the solutions.

Comment: Added Embed for clarification.